# Uncertainty of inverse cosine function

Tags: trigonometry, error-propagation

I am propagating uncertainties for a lab report in Physics. Anyways, I have a function:
$$cos⁡(θ_0 )=  \frac{0.725\space m-h}{0.675\space m}        $$
The uncertainty of both the numerator and denominator is $\pm 0.1\space$mm.
There are multiple values of $h$ but for the sake of demonstration, assume $h=0.05$ m.

How would I calculate the uncertainty of the angle, $\theta_0$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how to show it, but the $m$'s in the function are units, not variables. Sorry!

Comment: one possibility is to change the font to `\mathrm`, yet I would omit the unit completely in the equation.

Comment: Since we are in the range where RHS is close to $1$ we are in the domain were $\theta_0$ is close to $0$ and we can use Taylor series approximation and corresponding error. Although how do you deal with $h<0.05$ (i.e RHS>1) because in this case there are no solutions ?

Comment: First express $\theta_0$  and take the derivatives. Then go from $\delta$ to  $\Delta$  **adding** the errors

Comment: $$\cos(\theta_0 + \Delta\theta_0) = \cos(\theta_0) \pm \color{green}{\frac{\cos(\theta_0 + \Delta\theta_0) - \cos(\theta_0 - \Delta\theta_0)}{2}}$$ Exclude the uncertainties in the $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ part.

Comment: @zwim. May be $m$ is the name of a variable (which would be a bad choice in the context)

Comment: Is $\large m$ standing for meters or is it a quantity ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici See the first comment of OP, it is the unit (meters)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $h = 0.5 \, \mathrm{m}$,

$$\cos(\theta_0) = \frac{0.725 - 0.5}{0.675} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Using fractional uncertainties (as a consequence of taking derivatives),

\begin{align}
\frac{\Delta\cos(\theta_0)}{\cos(\theta_0)} &\approx \frac{\Delta\text{numerator}}{\text{numerator}} + \frac{\Delta\text{denominator}}{\text{denominator}} \\
\implies\Delta\cos(\theta_0) &\approx \frac{1}{3}
\left(\frac{0.0001}{0.725 - 0.5} + \frac{0.0001}{0.675}\right)\\
&\approx 0.0002
\end{align}

We can now write
\begin{align}
\Delta\cos(\theta_0) &= \frac{\cos(\theta_0 + \Delta\theta_0) - \cos(\theta_0 - \Delta\theta_0)}{2} \approx 0.0002\\
\cos(\theta_0 + \Delta\theta_0) - \cos(\theta_0 - \Delta\theta_0) &\approx0.0004
\end{align}

Using compound angle identities, we get
$$- 2\sin(\theta_0)\sin(\Delta\theta_0) \approx 0.0004$$

Substituting $\theta_0 = \cos^{-1}(1/3)$,
\begin{align}
\frac{-4\sqrt{2}}{3}\sin(\Delta\theta_0) &\approx 0.0004\\
\implies \sin(\Delta\theta_0) &\approx \frac{-0.0004\times3}{4\sqrt{2}}\\ 
\implies |\Delta\theta_0| &\approx \boxed{0.01^{\circ}}
\end{align}